# Text-align css is not working

Tags: html, css

I have a links bar at the top of my page with three links: **Learn**, **Affiliate Content**, and then a profile link connected to a dropdown. I want the profile link to be on the right, and the two others to be on the left.

```css
#top-links-bar{padding:30px;border:0px solid black;background: linear-gradient(gray, white);}

.caret{border-left:5px solid transparent;border-right:5px solid transparent;border-top:5px solid black;display:inline-block;
margin-top:5px;vertical-align:middle;transition:all 2s;}

.caret:hover{border-top:5px solid green; cursor:pointer}

.top-link{font-family:romeral; color:#1851EE; padding:30px; transition:color 2s, background 2s;}

.top-link:hover{color:gray;background:linear-gradient(white, gray);cursor:pointer;border-left:1px solid black;border-right:1px solid black;}

.dropdown{font-family:champagnelimo; background:linear-gradient(gray, green); z-index:200; height:150px; width:100%; padding:50px; border:4px solid gray; position:absolute; top:100px;}
 
.dropdown2{
border:3px solid grey; background:linear-gradient(to left, #37B732, orange); width:20%; position:relative; left:10%;}

.operation-your-profile{text-align:center; padding:20px; border-top:1px solid gray; border-bottom:1px solid gray;display:block;}
css
```

```html
<div id="top-links-bar">

<span class="top-link link-bar-link" id="learn">Learn <span class="caret"></span></span>

<span class="top-link link-bar-link" id="affiliate-content">Affiliate Content <span class="caret"></span></span>

<span class="top-link link-bar-link" id="account-profile" style="text-align:right;"><?php echo $_POST["name"];?> <span class="caret"></span></span>


</div>
<div id="affiliate-content-dropdown" class="dropdown">
<p style="font-size:20pt;"><b>Tutorial Content</b></p>
<ul style="list-style-type:square; font-size:15pt;">
<li><a href="http://othersite.com" target="_blank">OtherSite.com</a></li>

</div>

<div id="your-profile-dropdown" class="dropdown2">
    <span class="operation-your-profile">My Profile</span>
    <span class="operation-your-profile">Log Out</span>
</div>
```

The biggest problem is that there is nothing in the css that contradicts the style attribute! And even if there was, the inline rule would take precedence.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a Fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/crmLh63b/ **Note**: The dropdown links don't work; I used Jquery.

Comment: I think you're assuming that setting the `text-align` property on a span will actually cause the span's position to change relative to its parent. It actually just causes text inside the span to be right aligned.

Comment: But wouldn't `display:block` negate that?

Comment: No, because `text-align` means "the alignment of the text inside this node", not "where this node should appear within its parent". Whether it's displayed as a block or inline doesn't matter.

Comment: you solved your issue?

Comment: @yak613 The span with the name in it does not have `display:block`, so it is only as wide as its contents.

Comment: letme paste your code in html editor...just a min

Comment: keep trying...more few min... :)

Comment: I can slightly change the structure of your css ??

Comment: @JoãoLuizGrigoletti, it's been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create 3 css classes:

```
float-left { float: left;}
float-right {float: right;}
clear-float {clear: both;}
```

then you can try

```
 <span class="top-link link-bar-link float-left" id="learn">Learn <span class="caret"></span></span>

 <span class="top-link link-bar-link float-left"  id="affiliate-content" >Affiliate Content <span class="caret"></span></span>

 <span class="top-link link-bar-link float-right"  id="account-profile">trest <span class="caret"></span></span>

<div class="clear-float"></div>
```

You can also try something more semantic, like this:

CSS:

```
.caret{
    border-left:5px solid transparent;
    border-right:5px solid transparent;
    border-top:5px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:5px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    transition:all 2s; 
    margin-left:4px;

}


#top-links-bar{
    padding:5px;
    border:0px solid black;
    background: linear-gradient(gray, white);
}
#top-links-bar ul{
    display: block;
    list-style : none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#top-links-bar ul li a{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 17px 17px;
    position: relative;
}
#top-links-bar ul li a:hover{
    color:gray;
    background:linear-gradient(white, gray);
    cursor:pointer;
    border-left:1px solid black;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    padding: 17px 16px;
}
#top-links-bar ul li:last-child {
    float:right;
}
```

The HTML menu

```
<div id="top-links-bar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Learn<span class="caret"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Affiliate Content<span class="caret"></span></a</li>
        <li><a href="#"><?php echo $_POST["name"];?><span class="caret"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>


</div>
```

Comment: Why the `!important`? What need do you have to include that?

Comment: a CSS declaration with ! important assumes the highest priority in the Cascade order and is second only to another statement with ! important more specific.

Comment: This is a kind of hack in css . Try not to use , but when u need override a rule , this is the fastest way

Comment: to replace the changes that were made in that property. How not know your whole by code , put to prioritize this change

Comment: Should definitely try to avoid the !important declaration and avoid inline CSS altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Text align is applied to the text inside, it does not align the span or container it is applied to.

The item you want positioned need to either use position or a float to get there.

```
position: absolute; right:0; top:0;
```

Or...

```
float:right;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated fiddle that cleans up the code a bit so it is readable and corrects a few things:  http://jsfiddle.net/crmLh63b/2/

First, you shouldn't really have spans inside of spans.  Spans shouldn't really have any other container in them, so I changed those to divs.  Then if we float the content areas they sit a lot nicer than absolutely positioning (although feel free to change that back based on how your dropdowns with jQuery work).

You also had an unclosed `<ul>` in there.

Then if we float your first to header items to the left, and float the third item by targeting the `#account-profile` ID we can float that to the right to give you the desired affect.  Updated Code below:

HTML:

```
<div id="top-links-bar">
    <div class="top-link link-bar-link" id="learn">
        Learn <span class="caret"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="top-link link-bar-link" id="affiliate-content">
        Affiliate Content <span class="caret"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="top-link link-bar-link" id="account-profile">
        <?php echo $_POST["name"];?> <span class="caret"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="affiliate-content-dropdown" class="dropdown">
    <p style="font-size:20pt;"><b>Tutorial Content</b></p>
    <ul style="list-style-type:square; font-size:15pt;">
         <li><a href="#" target="_blank">OtherSite.com</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="your-profile-dropdown" class="dropdown2">
    <span class="operation-your-profile">My Profile</span>
    <span class="operation-your-profile">Log Out</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #top-links-bar {
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
      padding:30px;
      background: linear-gradient(gray, white);
 }
 .caret {
      border-left:5px solid transparent;
      border-right:5px solid transparent;
      border-top:5px solid black;
      display:inline-block;
      margin-top:5px;
      vertical-align:middle;
      transition:all 2s;
 }
 .caret:hover {
      border-top:5px solid green;
      cursor:pointer
 }
 .top-link {
      float: left; 
      font-family:romeral;
      color:#1851EE; 
      padding:30px; 
      transition:color 2s, 
      background 2s;
 }
 #account-profile.top-link {
      float: right;
 }
 .top-link:hover {
      color:gray;
      background:linear-gradient(white, gray);
      cursor:pointer;
      border-left:1px solid black;
      border-right:1px solid black;
}
.dropdown {
    float: left; 
    font-family:champagnelimo;
     background:linear-gradient(gray, green); 
     z-index:200; 
     height:150px; 
     width:100%; 
     padding:50px; 
     border:4px solid gray;  
}
ul li:visited {
     color:blue;
}
.dropdown2 {
     float: left;
     margin-left: 10%;
     border:3px solid grey;
     background:linear-gradient(to left, #37B732, orange);
     width:20%;
     position:relative;
}
.operation-your-profile{
   text-align:center;
   padding:20px;
   border-top:1px solid gray;
   border-bottom:1px solid gray;
   display:block;  
}
```

There is probably still a lot of cleaning up to do to make it as crisp as you can, but this should be a good starting point.

Comment: thanks. What i find strange is that the font I used for the dropdown links stayed the same.

Comment: It wouldn't change...it has the same class applied to it so regardless of whether it is a DIV or a SPAN the same CSS properties are connected to it.

Comment: That's not the point. How did JSFiddle _get_ the font? But it doesn't really matter

Comment: It was directly from the original code YOU posted.........I just copied/pasted it into a fiddle.......

Comment: It's not the code, it's the font. You noticed the other font rendered as a plain sans-serif font? This one (it's called "Romeral") actually displayed properly. Does JSFiddle have that font or something?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  It doesn't display for me properly so it may be a font you have installed on your system specifically.  Interesting.